# jwplayer memory leak / not releasing memory on subsequent loads

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I've an HTML Page crafted using JavaScript on which I've used JW Player. For some reason, its not releasing memory. The logical flow is like:

Step 1: Load HTML Page.
Step 2: Fetch content details using AJAX Request.
Step 3: Load first Video using JW Player.
Step 4: Unload JW Player using `jwplayer("#jwplayerdivcontainer").remove()`.
Step 5: Load next Video using JW Player.

Somehow, between Step 4 and Step 5, memory is not getting freed despite calling `remove()` method and it gets subsequently increased causing memory leak and browser crash at later stage.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !!!

**UPDATE**

I've tried to call `.remove()` method, `.detachMedia()` method and nothing is working as expected.

On digging more using Chrome and Mozilla Profilers, I found that `jwplayer` instance is not getting destroyed.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Cerbrus - have updated with the methods I've tried.

Comment: Do you have some example code that shows how you set it up?

Comment: @Quince - Sorry about that as code is made for the client and cannot disclose much.

Comment: without seeing any code then my first guess would be a listener that has been setup that is not being cleared? do you set up and listeners independently of the plugins API, I mean not off of the jwplayer objectas those should be cleared automatically when calling remove.

Comment: We do not have any listeners created independently.

Comment: Do you have a link? Can you put up a test page that has placeholder videos that will demonstrate the issues without causing issues for the client?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer - Is there any way I can send you private message?

Comment: I've derived the solution by putting JW Player instance constant on the page. Whenever video needs to be changed, I call the same instance and change the video. Please let me know if this is the correct solution.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer - Do you have any better solution?

Comment: Can you email us a link so we can see what you have come up with? support <at> jwplayer <dot> com, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was as tired as you and finally found the solution by trying it.

```
jwplayer("playerArea").detachMedia();
```